# Programmatically add product to Virtuemart?

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

For a customer I am building a Virtuemart 2.0.26d website.

Because of a local law, for each unit of a product that is ordered a fee must be added.

So, when ordering 4 products, the fee must be charged 4 times. By law it is required that the total sum of this fee is visible on the invoice/order confirmation.

I looked at the price rules in Virtuemart, but they don't seem to have an option for this. There is a price modifier after tax, but then the fee is visibile as an negative discount. Something I don't want.

The only solution I came up with is to make a new product for the fee and programmatically add this product for each unit. Can this be done by making a Virtuemart Plugin, or must I change the core for this?

Or are there better solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can add extra charge by Taxes & Calculation Rules.
create new rules and select tax per product for Type of Arithmetic Operation and select Math Operation + Or +% as per you want to add extra fee per product.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom field to each product with the fee amount and alter the code of the payment plugin to add this fee to your order.